# Sum of Char string

Tags: c

I have to write a function to find the sum of the numbers from a string. The sum needs to be printed out for each row in main. I'm using strtok and token to strip off comma's. Then atof to convert string to double. I'm heaving hard time to connect these pieces togather.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int i;
    double sum=0;

    char* str[] = {"12, 34, 56, 78",
        "82.16, 41.296",
        "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
        "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9"};

    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str));i++)
    {
        //print//
        printf("sum = %3.6f \n",sum);
    }
 }

double sum(char* s[])
{
    const char str[100];
    char *token;
    char *del = ", ";

    token = strtok(str, del);

    while( token != NULL )
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, del);
    }

    double atof( const char *s
    double n;
    double sum=0;
    for(n=0;n<str(s);n++)
    {
        sum = sum + s[n];
    }
    return (sum);
  }
```

Comment: "hard time to connect these pieces togather" is not question.  Please provide **specific** details of what the problem is.

Comment: The function should count sum of each row. for example                            For 12, 34, 56, 78
  sum = 180.000000

Comment: Well, for starters at least call the `sum` function. And then continue from there. If you want help then you need to tell us more specifically what it is you don't know how to do or are stuck on. Don't just tell us what you want to do, tell us why it is you aren't able to do it.

Comment: Sorry i'll be more specific.

Comment: In `main`, you have a variable called `sum`. Step 1 is to rename that. Otherwise, you can't call the function `sum`.

Comment: Is my function computation for sum seems ok. I know there are errors but i'm unable to fix them.

Comment: In `token = strtok(str, del);` the variable `str` is *unintialised*. Also, you must extract the numbers from the tokens *within the `while` loop*.

Comment: Please add the prototype `double sum(char* s[]);` above `main` when you add the call, otherwise the compiler will make wrong assumptions about it (if it even allows).

Comment: @WeatherVane can you please give me example.

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: for(i=0;i<(sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str));i++)
    {
        double sum(char* s[]);            
        can i do it like this? or how can i call the method in printf                                                                                                    printf("sum = %3.6f \n",double sum(char* s[]));
    }   
}

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand why you have repeated `main` in comment.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to be specific :(

Comment: You need to study the books a bit more, how to call a function and get a return value.

Comment: double getSum=sum(char* s[]);
        printf("sum = %3.6f \n",getSum)

Comment: http://ideone.com/3umold

Comment: I appreciate everyones help Thank you.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY your'e awesome I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ideone.com/3umold](http://ideone.com/3umold) – BLUEPIXY

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double sum(const char s[]);

int main(void) {
    int i;
    //double sum=0;

    char* str[] = {
        "12, 34, 56, 78",
        "82.16, 41.296",
        "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
        "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9"
    };

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str); i++){
        //print
        printf("sum = %f \n", sum(str[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}

double sum(const char s[]){
    char str[100];
    char *token, *del = ", ";
    double sum = 0.0;

    strcpy(str, s);
    token = strtok(str, del);

    while( token != NULL ){
        sum += atof(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, del);
    }
    return sum;
}
```